# Why symfony can't find template it rendered in other function

Tags: symfony

I have a function in my controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace GradeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use GradeBundle\Entity\User;
use GradeBundle\Entity\SchoolClass;

class MainController extends Controller
{
/**
* @Route("/", name="index_page")
*/
public function index()
{

  return $this->render('GradeBundle:Default:index.html.twig');

}
```

It renders the twig template correctly. However when I use other function:

```
  /**
    * @Route("/adminNew", name="add_admin")
    */

    public function addAdmin()
    {
       $session = new Session();

      if($session->get('loggedIn') == null)
         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index_page'));
      else
        return $this->render('GradeBundle:Add:newAdmin.html.twig');

    }
```

I have the following error:

```
Unable to find template "GradeBundle:Default:index.twig.html".
```

Does anybody have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be indexAction and addAdminAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo somewhere you call template:

```
GradeBundle:Default:index.twig.html
```

But you have only `GradeBundle:Default:index.html.twig` template.

Note the difference: `html.twig` `twig.html`

I suspect that you extend it in `GradeBundle:Add:newAdmin.html.twig` by:

```
{% extends 'GradeBundle:Default:index.twig.html' %}
```

but should be:

```
{% extends 'GradeBundle:Default:index.html.twig' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to use the correct namespace for the Controller you're using? And are you including the correct files? Also I'm not sure I understand the question correctly - are you saying if you add another function with a different twig file render, the first one no longer renders? Could I see your class names and the namespaces / use statements?

Usually in these instances, it's that the templates are in the wrong place or the correct file is not included in order to find it.

Michael